# Search in table where column value is exact in a specific string

Tags: mysql, laravel

I try to search in "ProductType" table for a specific text from an api, but I get a null value.

This is my code:

```
$product_type = ProductType::where('b2b_string', $b2b_product->product)->orWhere('variant', 'LIKE', '%' . $b2b_product->product_variant . '%')->first();
```

In my databse, `'variant'` column value is:

```
"DAC Grade: <b>Edition</b><br /> Output: <b>SE</b>"
```

And from API, `$b2b_product->product_variant` gives me this result:

```
"Colour: <b>Silver</b><br /> DAC Grade: <b>Edition</b><br /> Output: <b>SE</b><br /> Voltage: <b>220V</b>"
```

How can i use LIKE operator to gives me the specific product_type?

Comment: You can try locate()

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution. Instead of

```
`orWhere('variant', 'LIKE', '%' . $b2b_product->product_variant . '%')`
```

I use

```
orWhereRaw('? REGEXP variant', [$b2b_product->product_variant])
```

( REGEXP => regular expression search).